# How to check length of a char in C

Tags: c, string, char

I want to write an if-else statement that checks if a char inputted is the length of 1.

```c
char temp;

printf("Enter colour: ");
scanf(" %c", &temp);

if (strlen(temp) > 1) {
    printf("Value most only be one character");
}

else {
    nextFunction();
}
```

However, using strlen() here makes my program halt and I don't know why. I also tried changing the third line to `scanf(" %s", &temp)` but this didn't work either. How else can I check and handle the length of the char input?

Comment: I think you're confused about the difference between a `char` and an array of `char`s. Also,  read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings .

Comment: `char` will always contain exactly 1 character. You need to use an array to read multiple characters.

Comment: `temp` being a `char` will always hold a single character. Maybe you want to read the input as a string (an array of `char`s), and then validate its length.

Comment: A char has always a length of 1. `sizeof ( char )` gives 1. If you want to check multibyte inputs, you at least need `%s` instead of `%c`.

Comment: I'd read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. This issue should have been detected by compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading and storing a single character by definition.

A variable of type `char` stores a single character value - `'A'`, `'\n'`, `'5'`, etc.

Your `scanf` call only reads a single character - the format string `" %c"` tells `scanf` to skip over any whitespace and read the next non-whitespace character, which gets stored to `temp`.

The `strlen` call is blowing up because it expects the argument to be a *pointer* to the the first character of a 0-terminated *string* - basically, an address, and no single character value is going to be a valid pointer value.

In this case the `strlen` call is unnecessary - all you really need to do is check the return value of `scanf` to make sure the input operation succeeded.  `scanf` will return the number of input items successfully read and assigned or `EOF` on end of file or error:

```
if ( scanf( " %c", &temp ) == 1 )
  // do something with temp
else
  // EOF or error
```

If you want to store a *string*, then you need to create an *array* of `char`:

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20 // or however long your string can be
...
char str[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1]; // +1 for the string terminator

if ( scanf( "%s", str ) == 1 ) // note no & operator
  // do something with str
```

This is not safe - if you enter a string that's longer than the array can hold, those excess characters will be written to the memory following the array, potentially overwriting something important.

You can make that safer by specifying a maximum width in the format specifier:

```
scanf( "%20s", str );
```

but it has to be hardcoded - you can't use a runtime parameter like you can with `printf`.  You can create a preprocessor macro that will expand to `"%20s"` (or whatever you set `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` to):

```
#define EXP(x) #x
#define FMT(x) "%" EXP(x) "s"

if ( scanf( FMT(MAX_STRING_LENGTH), str ) == 1 )
  // do something with str
```

but it's just safer and easier to use `fgets` instead:

```
if ( fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin ) )
  // do something with str
```

The only hitch here is that `fgets` will store the trailing newline to the array if there's room, so you'll have to handle that somehow:

```
size_t end = strlen( str );  
if ( str[end] == '\n' )      
  str[end] = 0;
```